# I tried install ubuntu 20.04 but get error

Tags: 20.04, system-installation

I get an error and after that computer freezing.

Error:
The attempt to mount a file system with type vfat in /dev/nvme0n1p1 at /boot/efi failed. You may resume partitioning from the partitioning menu.

What this error means and how I can fix this? I can't do anything after getting an error.

Answer (score 1):

It means the partition on the /dev/nvme0n1p1 is not formatted vfat a requirement of the `EFI` boot specification. To solve it before doing the partitioning steps in the `Terminal` program `sudo mkfs.vfat /dev/nvme0n1p1` be aware this will wipe everything on this partition, if it already has a boot loader it will be erased. Then try your partitioning again to see it it accepts it. If still complaing about the mount then `sudo mount /dev/nvme0n1p1 /boot/efi` before doing the partitioning steps again. Making certain it has selected or you have, the partition to be used as the System boot partition, however that option is worded, my memory fails me for the exact naming. All of this is conditional on you wanting to install to an `NVM-e` drive if trying to do this on a `SSD` it is installing the boot loader on a different drive and the `NVM-e` should be disconnected until the install finishes.